# Unknown arg `--hashlimit-upto'

Tags: iptables, ddos

I'm trying to prevent loic attackes by using this command

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 50/min \
--hashlimit-burst 500 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name http -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

reference: [How to prevent a LOIC (DDOS) attack?](https://serverfault.com/questions/211135/how-to-prevent-a-loic-ddos-attack)

I always got this error message:

```
iptables v1.3.5: Unknown arg `--hashlimit-upto'
```

What's causing it and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could it be that `v1.3.5` does not yet support that option? Check your man page, please. Is this an older box?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've updated to latest version which is v1.4.21, I'm still getting the error: iptables v1.4.21: unknown option "--hashlimit-upto"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an [ancient version of iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/news.html#2006-01-31) which dates back to January 2006, and probably on a very old Linux distribution.

The problem is that the feature you were trying to use was [added to iptables in 2008](https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/commit/extensions/libxt_hashlimit.c?id=9a8c77fc8df3155747c34dcea79b7834a2a9a40a).

The solution is to update to a more modern Linux distribution.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Hampton, please check my comment on my question, any idea?

Comment: Right? And did you update your kernel too? Exactly what are you running?

Comment: I'm using centos 5.9, is it risky to update kernel for this?

Comment: You can replace the kernel if you want, but you're already out of supportable territory by replacing standard utilities with self-compiled things. Better to update to a more current OS distribution if you want more current features.